I wanna know the exact meaning of mysterious 'that' in the beginning of the speech
I don't know the meaning of mysterious 'that' in the beginning of the clip. the address of the clip is here. https://www.youtube.com/shorts/t7OA_8cvLUc
(That I get really shy when I am speaking English and when I am doing interviews, ````)
please check and answer. I wanna know the exact meaning of 'that'.

It means nothing. It is an error. This person is not a native speaker. Possibly what she said before was edited out.

It's an answer to an interview question. Full context here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qHHczHsLCo#t=3m23s

If there was a question asked, the video clip has lost the context, and is beginning "in the middle of things".
